# Como dar espacios en una navbar

Tags: html, css, web

Estoy empezando a practicar html, css y js. Tengo una navbar que contiene 5 li, lo que quiero es darle un espacio a ldo izquierdo y tambien en medio a la navbar, pero nose como. Tengo lo siguiente:
mi archivo de Html

```css
body {margin: 0;}
    
    .conatiner{
      margin-left: 70px;
    }
    
    ul.topnav {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #A3A656;
    }
    
    ul.topnav li {float: left;}
    
    ul.topnav li a {
      display: block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #384001;}
    
    ul.topnav li.right {float: right;}
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      ul.topnav li.right, 
      ul.topnav li {float: none;}
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/styles.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="topnav">
                    <li><a href="#">PROMOCIONES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FOTOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SERVICIOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">MAPA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACTO</a></li>
                    <li class="right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="right"><a href="#about">Mi cuenta</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

esta es la imagen de como deberia esta mi navbar, nose si lo este haciendo mal o que me falta, lo que deseo es tener 70px al inicio de la navbar y en medio lo mismo de espacio, les agradecería su ayuda.
[image: como deberia ser la navbar]

Comment: Tal vez display flex pueda ayudar, le dará el espacio que necesita: `.topnav { display: flex; justify-content: space-between;  padding: 0 70px;}`